# Removing the list of columns from csv file with index

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a CSV file with content as follows:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
1,10,19,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,11,20,,,,,,,,,,,,,
3,12,21,,,,,,,,,,,,,
4,13,22,,,,,,,,,,,,,
5,14,23,,,,,,,,,,,,,
6,15,24,,,,,,,,,,,,,
7,16,25,,,,,,,,,,,,,
8,17,26,,,,,,,,,,,,,
9,18,27,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I need to remove some set of columns by index.

I tried the following code, It is not returning the result as expected, Someone help me with the same.

```
import csv

def read():
    with open("test.csv", "rb") as fp_in, open("newfile.csv", "wb") as fp_out:
        reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
        col_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
        for row in reader:
            for col_item in col_list:
                print(col_item)
                del row[int(col_item)]
            writer.writerow(row)
read()
```

Result returned:

```
1,3,5,7,9,11,13,14
10,,,,,,,
11,,,,,,,
12,,,,,,,
13,,,,,,,
14,,,,,,,
15,,,,,,,
16,,,,,,,
17,,,,,,,
18,,,,,,,
```

Issue is because reader will be same always for each iteration, I need to remove all the columns in list.

Someone help me with the same.

Desired output should be something like this:

```
7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
.
.
.
.
```

To be precise  I just wanted to remove mentioned columns and it values.

Edit:

Some clear example.

```
def read():
    with open("test.csv", "rb") as fp_in, open("newfile.csv", "wb") as fp_out:
        reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
        col_list = [0,2]
        for row in reader:
            for col_item in col_list:
                print(col_item)
                del row[int(col_item)]
            writer.writerow(row)
read()
```

Output I got:

```
1,2,4
v,d,q
c,s,a
s,d,d
f,x,c
```

Expected:

```
1,3,4
v,s,q
c,d,a
s,f,d
f,a,c
```

Comment: show the desired result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thanks , Added the desired result!

Comment: Just to confirm - so you want to remove some of the columns (e.g. 1, 3, 4, 5) and then transpose the first value of some rows (but not all - e.g. 10, 12, 15) as columns? Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @priboyd I just wanted to remove the mentioned columns and the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're mutating the row on each iteration of col_list.

This should work; using a list comprehension to make a copy of the row without the indices in col_list.

```
def read():
    with open("test.csv", "r") as fp_in, open("newfile.csv", "w") as fp_out:
        reader = csv.reader(fp_in, delimiter=",")
        writer = csv.writer(fp_out, delimiter=",")
        col_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8]
        for row in reader:
            output = [v for (i,v) in enumerate(row) if i not in col_list]
            writer.writerow(output)
```

Which writes the following to newfile.csv:

```
7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Assuming your input file is called `input.txt`

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [k.split(',') for k in f.read().splitlines()]


for k in data:
    print(k[7] + ',' + ','.join(k[9:]))
```

And if you want to save the result into a file (called for example `final_file.txt`), you can do something like this:

```
with open("final_file.txt", 'a') as f:
    for k in data:
        f.write(k[7] + ',' + ','.join(k[9:]) + '\n')
```

Output:

```
7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
```

Comment: I just wanted to remove mentioned columns not as a range!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with pandas to `drop` specific columns then write to csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = df.drop(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','8'], axis=1)
df.to_csv('newfile.csv',index=False)
```

`newfile.csv` will be:

```
7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Can we do without Pandas library?!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [iloc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) within the [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library.

```
import pandas as pd

# load csv file
df = pd.read_csv('newfile.csv')

# store all rows + 1st, 2nd, 5th and 6th columns into another df
modified_df = df.iloc[:, [0, 1, 4, 5]] 

# print out
print(modified_df)
```